# Did any linguists try to popularize "casus causativus", to rectify the mistranslated "accusative"?

Tags: terminology

"accusative" hails from *accusare*, which the Romans chose

> [somewhat inaccurately to translate Greek *(ptōsis) aitiatike* "(case) of that which is caused" based on the similarity of the Greek word to the Greek verb *aitiasthai* "to accuse." Greek *aitia* is the root of both, and means "cause" as well as "accusation," hence the confusion of the Romans. A more correct translation would have been *casus causativus*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=accuse).

Was there ever a movement to implement and popularize [the more correct translation of *casus causativus*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=accuse)? This feels effortless to accomplish in Germanic and Romance languages...this would be translated "causative case" in English. If so, why did they fail? If not, why not?

#### accuse

> [13] *Accuse* comes via Old French
> *acuser* from the Latin verb *accūsāre*, which was
> based on the noun *causa* ‘cause’ – but cause in
> the sense not of ‘something that produces a
> result’, but of ‘legal action’ (a meaning
> preserved in English *cause list*, for instance).
> Hence *accūsāre* was to ‘call someone to account
> for their actions’.
>       The grammatical term *accusative* [15]
> (denoting the case of the object of a verb in Latin
> and other languages) is derived ultimately from
> *accūsāre*, but it arose originally owing to a
> mistranslation. The Greek term for this case was
> *ptósis aitiātiké* ‘case denoting causation’ – a
> reasonable description of the function of the
> accusative. Unfortunately the Greek verb
> *aitiásthai* also meant ‘accuse’, and it was this
> sense that Latin grammarians chose to render
> when adopting the term.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 4.

Comment: Why do both your links just go to a search page on Etymonline? (I’ve never seen anyone suggest or use ‘causative’ for this case name, probably because ‘accusative’ is so entrenched and because ‘causative’ has since developed a very different meaning within linguistics, so it would only be adding confusion. And it’s not like ‘causative’ describes the case any better than ‘accusative’ does.)

Comment: Varro chose accusativus, but Priscian, much later, did call it a causativus.

Comment: Linguistic theories evolve, and it's ok even if originally accusativus could have been misunderstood by the Roman grammarians. It doesn't matter. For instance, Aristotle used ptosis (case) to describe both noun and verb endings (and much more). Now, the accusative is used in a very specific, technical sense - typically the core meaning of the accusative is "the affected participant in a transitive clause" https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199206476.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199206476-e-37

Comment: two thousand years ago or more it could have made *some* difference - now it's too late and it doesn't really matter

Comment: This curiosity in the history of linguistics could be extremely useful to let's say L1 Russian learners, who I am sure get puzzled by the Latin calque винительный падеж (vinitel'nji padezh), because very quickly do they realize that the accusative case expresses much more than just "accusation". That being said, it's good you've been reading John Ayto's book *Word origins* - isn't it a compelling read?!

Comment: @AlexB. Some scholars seem to think it is not too late to change names like "aorist" and "imperfect".

Comment: By the way, this question is an exact duplicate of https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15559/why-didnt-latin-grammarians-ever-rectify-their-latin-mistranslation-of-ptōsis

Comment: @fdb No, this isn't "an exact duplicate". That question asks about why the dead Romans  didn't rectify their  mistranslation of Ancient Greek. This question asks why, millennia after the Romans, (modern) linguists didn't rectify either.